# Output always 65535 characters?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s.length();
    return 0;
}
```

why it gives output as 65535 even if i increase characters in s.
I have added the samle input here https://ideone.com/c2V8YX

Comment: It probably is the console that limits you to 65535 characters for a single input.

Comment: How can i get the length for such case?

Comment: Try reading from `cin` again and add that into `s`.

Comment: did you import string?

Comment: Tried that still gives same output

Comment: is not initialized....??

Comment: instead of trying to read the from the console can you store it in a file and read the file?

Comment: No,because this string will be a test case in coding website

Answer (score 5):

The Ideone FAQ answers:

> What is the size limit for the source code, input and output?
>
> 64 kB.

Note that this limitation has nothing to do with C++ language, or even the particular implementation of it. The limitation is by Ideone (and it's understandable. You wouldn't want to allow people to upload unlimited data to fill up your server). It appears that their behaviour is to silently truncate the input.

Comment: Huh, seems kinda silly that the main editor refuses links if they're not accompanied by code. edit: Yup, I meant to this site specifically; the basic concept is good, but clearly the implementation is lacking :)

Comment: @underscore_d Unfortunately they didn't make a smarter filter that would allow links to non-code on code demo services. Maybe someone should bring this up on meta.

Comment: So how can i get length?should i use character array but the input is not character

Comment: @jitendrakumhar you don't get the length, because the input that you give is not the input that ideone uses. Ideone throws away part of your string, and the program only receives some of it. Your program cannot get the length of something that it doesn't get as input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly wonderful code but the general idea seems sound. Basically reading chunks and appending them (probably to a buffewr as opposed to a raw string) but ya get the idea

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string all;
char snippet[100];
while(cin.get(snippet, 100)){ all += snippet; }
cout<< all.length() << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah! That piece of the puzzle "ideone" was missing. Hence forget this - user2079303 spotted the flaw in the whole plan.